# Setting a numeric scale in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph, geospatial, scale

I am trying to compare an extreme flood event occurring in 2022 to the historical mean of rainfall for February.
[This is my current map of Historical data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J63rO.png)
and
[This is the flood event](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FJIGg.png)

as shown the scale is set to the data so the graphs look more or less the same in colour,
but I want to do a side by side comparison to show how extreme the event was in Feb 2022. Therefore, I need to specify a scale for both maps.

It should be:
above 281 is extreme
mid 195
and low is below 140.

I cant figure out how to set this though.

this is my current code for graphs:

historical means:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(sf)
library(tidyverse)
ggplot()+
ggtitle("Map Of The Northern River's Local Goverment Areas (LGA's)")+
geom_sf(aes(geometry = combined_data2$geometry, fill= combined_data2$Historical_means.Historical_means_agg), lwd = 0) +              
 theme_void() +                    
labs(fill = "Historical Feburary Rainfall Mean")
```

feb 2022 means :

```
library(ggplot2)
library(sf)
library(tidyverse)
ggplot()+
ggtitle("Map Of The Northern River's Local Goverment Areas (LGA's)")+
geom_sf(aes(geometry = combined_data1$geometry, fill= combined_data1$Rainfall_2022.Rainfall_2022), lwd = 0) +              
 theme_void() +                    
labs(fill = "Rainfall Mean Feburary 2022")
```

thanks for the help!

set a scale for ggplot

Comment: Have you seen this? https://www.r-bloggers.com/2022/07/how-to-set-axis-limits-in-ggplot2-3/ ? You can set `xlim()` and `ylim()` to whatever axes limits that you like. If you set the same, e.g., y axis limits for both graphs, they will appear on the identical y axis scale.